# Internet Explorer blocking Jquery and ruining my site

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Is there a way to prevent Internet Explorer from throwing up a security message (the yellow bar) every time my site loads up.

For example, I'm working on a microsite at the moment which uses Jquery to automatically brings up a lightbox when the page loads. This works fine in Chrome, Firefox etc. However, in IE the yellow bar jumps up and gives the following message:

"To help protect your security, your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer. Click here for options"

Obviously this means that the lightbox doesn't appear until the user clicks on 'Allow blocked content'. It's essential that the lightbox is displayed before anything else, so I'd really like to bypass the security message. Is there a way to code my site so that this doesn't happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that only happens if you call the page locally, e.g. you have C:\index.html in your address bar; try uploading you code to your server and seeing if that eliminates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is the warning coming up during local development? In most cases once it is deployed to a server it will work fine, without error.